# Unable to connect to mongo-db with replicaSet name in connection string

Tags: mongodb

I am new using mongodb. I have installed mongo-db on an ec2 instance and started the same using the following command,

```
mongod --dbpath /tmp/data --logpath /tmp/logs/mongo.log --replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all
```

when I execute rs.isMaster() after connecting to mongo I get the following output,

```
{
  topologyVersion: {
    processId: ObjectId('65ba044d42974235103bb852'),
    counter: Long('6')
  },
  hosts: [ 'ip-172-XX-XX-XXX.ap-XXX-1.compute.internal:27017' ],
  setName: 'rs0',
  setVersion: 1,
  ismaster: true,
  secondary: false,
```

In the response the host points to the private DNS of my ec2 instance.

When I then proceed to connect to the database using the following connection string,

```
mongodb://ec2-13-XXX-XX-XX.ap-XXX-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/local?replicaSet=rs0
```

I get the following error in the logs,

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: No such host is known (ip-172-XX-XX-XXX.ap-XXX-1.compute.internal)
```

How to resolve the issue? Why I do not receive any error when not mentioning the "replicaSet" parameter in the connection string?

Kind Regards,